# Performing complex aggregate on two lists of columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to programming and am cleaning up and simplifying my code to perform groupby and aggregation on a pyspark dataframe. I am trying to make things easier to follow and have been working on refactoring some of my code. When I try the following code, I get an error:

```python
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column:
```

Here is my code:

```python
groupBy = ['ColA']

convert_to_list = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3',]
convert_to_set = ['Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6',]

fun_list = [F.collect_list]
funs_set = [F.collect_set]

exprs = F.concat(
    [f(F.col(c)) for f in fun_list for c in convert_to_list], 
    [f(F.col(c)) for f in funs_set for c in convert_to_set]
)

df = df.groupby(*groupBy).agg(*exprs)
```

Really appreciate your help. I am unsure how to pass the right columns to the agg function.

Sample input and expected output

[image]

[image: an]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please provide a sample Input data and expected output besides your code? It helps users solving your issue. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the call to `concat` - you're passing in 2 lists, when it excepts columns. Try `exprs = [f(F.col(c)) for f in fun_list for c in convert_to_list] + [f(F.col(c)) for f in funs_set for c in convert_to_set]` instead. Or maybe you want `exprs = concat(*([f(F.col(c)) for f in fun_list for c in convert_to_list] + [f(F.col(c)) for f in funs_set for c in convert_to_set]))`. Hard to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: @pault, The first method worked! The reasoning makes perfect sense too. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the call to [`concat`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) - you're passing in 2 lists, when it expects the arguments to be columns. It seems that you wanted to concatenate these lists together, which can be done using the addition operator in python.

Try:

```python
exprs = (
    [f(F.col(c)).alias(c) for f in fun_list for c in convert_to_list] + 
    [f(F.col(c)).alias(c) for f in funs_set for c in convert_to_set]
)
```

I also added in a call to [`alias`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.alias) so the column names are maintained after the aggregation.

Comment: This works great, thanks. Now I tried to convert this to a UDF, and I get an error:
```
@F.udf
def aggregation(df, groupby_column, cols_to_list, cols_to_set):
  fun_list = [F.collect_list]
  funs_set = [F.collect_set]
  exprs = [F.collect_set(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in cols_to_list]\
          + [F.collect_set(F.col(c)).alias(c) in funs_set for c in cols_to_set]
  return df.groupby(*groupby_column).agg(*exprs)
```
```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame
```
Might you know what might be happening here?

Comment: It's hard to interpret code in a comment - try posting a new question, but be sure to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) and [don't post pictures of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Done. If you get an opportunity, I would really appreciate your help, Paul. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796231/how-to-convert-a-group-and-agg-code-on-a-dataframe-to-a-udf-in-pyspark